# Explicit formula for calculating number of transpositions

Tags: group-theory, permutations, determinant

If we have a permutation of the first N natural numbers, is there an explicit formula that can tell you if the permutation is even or odd. For example, $(2,3,1)$ is even as it requires minimum of 2 changes and $(1,3,2)$ is odd. Suppose, you denote the value at index $i$ by $k_i$. Is there a function $f(i,k_i)$ which will the give the answer as, say +1 for even and -1 for odd?

Comment: A cycle is an even permutation if it is has odd length; and an odd permutation if it has even length. The permutation is even if and only if when you express it as a product of disjoint cycles, the number of cycles of even length is even.

Comment: Let $f$ be the permutation, then the sign is$$\prod_{1\le j<k\le N}\frac{f(k)-f(j)}{k-j}\ ,$$ but this is useless in practice.

Comment: (I’m guessing from what you write that you’re expressing your permutations in abbreviated 2-line notation; that is, $(1,3,2)$ is the permutation mapping $1\mapsto 1$, $2\mapsto 3$, and $3\mapsto 2$. Please note that this is *not* standard when refering to permutations. Your notation is more likely to be (mis)interpreted as cycle notation).

Comment: @dan_fulea Thank you for the comment. I can verify that it works but do you have any reference for this? How do you prove that it holds in general? I am assuming you can remove the denominator as that is always positive.

Answer (score 0):

you can build a $k \times k$ matrix ($k = 3$ in your case) filled with zeroes, but put 1's at locations $2,3$ and $3,1$ and $1, 2$. Then take the determinant, and its sign will tell you whether the permutation is even or odd. And since the determinant is a polynomial, you're done. (You'll have to work out what to do with a permutation that's a PRODUCT of cycles, but I'm sure you can do so.)

Of course, this is hideously inefficient, but it will work...

Comment: If we write the formula for determinant in an explicit way, it itself uses the permutation symbol. That's actually the origin of my question. You basically took the formula for the determinant and put all the other terms to zero.

Comment: Well...that's one formula for the determinant. There's also the recursive one, the "unique alternating n-linear function", etc. Regardless, Arturo's answer is the one you really need anyhow.